# Fb Chatbot Menu on Mobile

Tags: php, android, facebook

**I have an issue in configuring chatbot Persistent menu. It is showing both menu and input field in browser.**

[image: see here]

**But not showing both input text field and menu in Facebook Messenger (Android Mobile).**

[image: See here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the solution. 
I was setting **"composer_input_disabled" = true** 
It should be like **false** in order to show both input and menu

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works, from my experience, is to **delete the conversation** from your Messenger mobile application and **then start the conversation again**.

If that doesn't work, a restart of the application between the deletion and the reinitialization of the conversation very often works.

Comment: I have tried the first solution, it did not worked.
But for the 2nd solution, should I have to remove my application from App developers console and then recreate it?

Comment: Your both solutions did not worked. I have posted the answer check that.

Comment: Great it seems I didn't understand your question as well as I should. Happy that you found a solution. :)